# C++ avoid casting in derived class code for twin container/contained object design

Tags: c++, containers, derived-class, upcasting

I have twin base classes for a container class and contained object (in my case, for a generic graph class made of linked nodes, but I guess the question would stand in all cases where you want to derive from both a container class and a contained object class from twin container/contained base classes). I want to use derived classes of both the container and contained object. How do I avoid having to constantly downcast the contained object to the derived contained object type when I access the container of the derived container class?

```
// a class that represents the graph
template <typename WrappedObject> class BaseGraph  {
  ... // constructor, virtual destructor, ...
public:
  std::map<WrappedObject*, BaseNode<WrappedObject> *> obj_to_node_map_;
  bool addEdge(WrappedObject *scr, WrappedObject *trg) {
    BaseNode<WrappedObject > * srcNode = getOrCreateNode(src);
    BaseNode<WrappedObject > * dstNode = getOrCreateNode(trg);
    return addEdge(srcNode, dstNode);
  }

  bool addEdge(BaseNode<WrappedObject> * src, BaseNode<WrappedObject> * trg) {
    if (src == trg) {
      return false;
    }

    src->suc_.insert(trg);
    trg->pre_.insert(src);
    return true;
  }

  BaseNode<WrappedObject>* getOrCreateNode(WrappedObject*obj){
    BaseNode<WrappedObject> *node = getNode(obj);
    if (node == nullptr) {
      node = createNode(obj);
      obj_to_node_map_[obj] = node;
    }
    return node;
  }

  BaseNode<WrappedObject>* createNode(WrappedObject* obj){
    BaseNode<WrappedObject> *node = allocateNode(obj);
    nodes_.push_back(node);
    return node;
  }
  BaseNode<WrappedObject>* getNode(WrappedObject*obj) const {
    auto it = obj_to_node_map_.find(obj);
    if (it == obj_to_node_map_.end()) {
      return nullptr;
    }
    return it->second;
  }
private:
  virtual BaseNode<Object> * allocateNode(Object *obj) = 0;

};
// a class that represents the vertices of the graph
template <typename WrappedObject>
class BaseNode {
  friend class BaseGraph<WrappedObject>;
public:
  typedef std::set<BaseNode *> Set;
  BaseNode(WrappedObject*obj):obj_(obj) {
  }
  virtual ~BaseNode() {};

  WrappedObject *obj_;
  Set suc_;
  Set pre_;
};

// derived classes for node and graph
class RealObject;
class MyNode : public BaseNode<RealObject> {
private:
  std::string name_;
  MyNode(RealObject *obj, std::string & name): BaseGraph<RealObject>(obj), name_(name) {}
...
};
class MyGraph: public BaseGraph<RealObject> {
  // constructor, virtual destructor, ...
private:
  virtual BaseNode<RealObject> * allocateNode(RealObject *obj) {
    return new MyNode(obj, this);
  }
  std::map<std::string, MyNode *> name_lu_map_;
public:
  MyNode * getNode(std:string & name) {
    return(name_lu_map_[name]);
  }
  // Have to have this otherwise any call to getNode on a MyGraph instance
  // will cause compiler error as getNode is overloaded in derived class
  MyNode * getNode(RealObject *obj) const {
    return static_cast<MyNode *>(BaseGraph<RealObject>::getNode(obj));
  }

  void myDerivedClassFunction(RealObject *obj) {
    // Lines like the following when I call a method of the base class
    // returning a base class pointer will require casting, which I find
    // ugly
    MyNode *node = static_cast<MyNode *>(getOrCreateNode(obj));
    node->name_ = <something>;
    ...
  }
};
```

Is there a design pattern that would allow to avoid all the awkward downcast to the derived class whenever I use methods of the container base class that return base class contained object pointers? I thought of using a template argument to define what the derived contained object type will be, but I do not see how I can describe in C++ the fact that a typename template argument derives from another class. Possibly, I am looking at this from the wrong angle. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use base class pointers anywhere you don't have to actually use functions that exist only in the derived class.  You haven't shown what you are doing with the object, so we can't tell if the cast is necessary.

Comment: Think you might be over-designing. Consider keeping the `Node` dead generic. Keep it stupid and don't inherit from it. Place the smarts inside a class that the `Node` contains.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am running under some assumptions which I have not explained: the derived class will contain many more methods and/or members that are not available to the base classes (both for graph and node) and therefore I need the base class pointers to be converted to derived if I want to use them in the client code of these classes.

Comment: For instance, I could want to acces the name_ member from the myDerivedClassFunction method of my derived class.

Comment: I stand by my earlier comment. You are combining different, unrelated responsibilities within the same class. This will result in a more complicated  architecture and more difficulties working with it.

Comment: Actually, I am doing the exact opposite: I refactored a class that used to have both some responsibility of supporting some GUI functions with lots of bells and whistles having to do with how to color/manage drawing style of arcs, and representing graph connectivity, and since I want to share only the connectivity representation with some other parts of the code, I am moving this functionality to a base class that different parts of the code will be able to inherit. I don't understand what you mean "keep it stupid". Could you try to provide more specific details about how you would change it?

Comment: A node representing connectivity only should not need a base and a derived class at all.  Any functionality needing a class hierarchy would usually be best off in the class that a node contains, not in the node.  Perhaps that is what @user4581301 is getting at.

Comment: Ok, let's just assume that I have good reasons for wanting to share the way to represent connectivity information using a unified representation between different derived classes. So essentially, you all agree that there is no way to avoid the down-casting in a design like this?